# I'm still having issues with CSS and Drop Down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

The third menu option should appear only when I select the second option, but it is already appearing when I select the first one.

To see the error, in the link below, go to the top menu and select the option **"Localizar Peças" -> "GM (Chevrolet)"**, the third menu already appears, but should only appear when selecting one of the options, such as **"Agile"** for example.

http://adessopecas.com.br/index.php?route=common/home

My CSS is:

```
#menu .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
#menu ul ul ul.dropdown-inner {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
#menu .nav li {
  position: relative;
}
#menu ul ul li:hover ul.dropdown-inner {
  display: block;
}


#list-unstyled ul ul ul.dropdown-inner2 {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
#list-unstyled .nav li {
  position: relative;
}
#list-unstyled ul ul li:hover ul.dropdown-inner2 {
  display: block;
}
```

Li in html is:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu dropdown-inner">
    <li>Option 1-1</li>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu dropdown-inner2">
            <li>Option 1-1</li>
            <li>Option 1-1</li>
            <li>Option 1-1</li>
        </ul>
    <li>Option 2-1</li>
    <li>Option 3-1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to provide us with some code man.

Comment: Edited with sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because of this rule:

```
#menu ul ul li:hover ul.dropdown-inner {
    display: block;
}
```

You're basically showing all children at the same time, on hover.
Instead, you need something clean but more specific, utilizing [direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

```
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

And get rid of:

```
#menu .dropdown-inner ul {
    display: table-cell;
}
```